# Laravel request hasFile not registered when uploading from android/ios chrome

Tags: php, laravel, file, mobile, upload

I have a strange issue when uploading files through an android/ios chrome browser.
I have a whole condition thatchecks

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   ...
   if ($request->hasFile('photos')) {
       $this->createPhotos($post, $request['photos']);
   }
   ...
}
```

And here is the createPhotos function

```
public function createPhotos(Post $post, $photos)
{
    
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        $p = Image::make($photo->getRealPath());
        $filename = md5($photo->getRealPath() . Carbon::now()) . '.jpg';
        $p->orientate();
        $p->resize(null, 500, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });

        $p->stream();

        Storage::disk(env('APP_FILESYSTEM'))->put('posts/' . $filename, $p);

        $average_color = $this->getAverageColor($photo->getRealPath());

        $post_photo = new \App\Photo();
        $post_photo->name = $filename;
        $post_photo->height = $p->height();
        $post_photo->width = $p->width();
        $post_photo->average_color = $average_color;
        $post_photo->post_id = $post->id;
        $post->photos()->save($post_photo);
    }
}
```

It works fine when uploading from desktop but the problem appears when uploading from mobile browser only. This whole hasFile condition gets skipped.

Comment: can you show your form?

Comment: Use the getContent() method of the Request class instead of the hasFile() method to check if the file is present in the request.

Add the following line of code to the top of your controller method:

$_FILES = $request->allFiles();

Comment: @AbbasMastan i managed to do exactly what you said and apparently now it gets the files but is unable to read them properly. Showing this error when uploading from mobile  Unsupported image type directory. GD driver is only able to decode JPG, PNG, GIF, BMP or WebP files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the things i was concerned about was the problem.. Apparently the problem was inside the server's php.ini file where `upload_max_filesize = 2M` ... and stubbornly i was constantly uploading smartphone camera photos larger than 2MB ...